# is there a way to get parameter types from a non-static method?

Tags: typescript, types

It's possible to get types of parameters as a tuple of a `static method` using `Parameteters<>`:

```js
class X {
    static fnStatic(a: number, b: string, d: Date) {}
}

type parameters = Parameters<typeof X.fnStatic>
```

but is there a way to do that with a `non-static method`?

```js
class X {
    fn(a: number, b: string, d: Date) {}
}

type parameters = Parameters<typeof X.fn> // error
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that a class in typescript is both a type and an object that exists at runtime. When you `typeof` something, you are asking for the type of a runtime available object. In this case, your class object. This gives you access to its static properties.

So instead, you want:

```
type parameters = Parameters<X['fn']>
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?jsx=2#code/MYGwhgzhAEAa0G8CwAoa7oDMB2AKMAXNNgK4C2ARgKYBOANNBURAC40CW2A5gwCZEARMCyoBKRAF9UUlKhYBPAA5VoABTA0wZKiJoRYAMWzQAvGo1adtCAB5YAbQDkORwF0AfKmAB7bKyze3kTqmtq6+kam0PYAjAyOYBTAjgzYVADu0EIiuKKuQA)

Leaving off `typeof` tells it to look at the type `X`, not the object available at runtime that is class `X`. And the `['prop']` notation is how you drill into a field of a type.

Comment: it was so obvious and simple, thanks for opening my eyes.